# Keras Neural Networks: saving weights with checkpoints or with save_weights?

Tags: networking, keras

So I have a quick question. I have 2 ways to save the weights of the Convolutional Neural Network that I am running.

1) I can do it while running the fit function with:

```
ModelCheckpoint('weights.{epoch:03d}-{val_acc:.4f}.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
```

and the file ends with nearly 13MB.

2) I can do it after the fit function finished with:

```
model.save_weights('final weights123123.hdf5')
```

and the file ends with nearly 4MB.

Then, the results on the test set are the same with both files. So my question is: What is the reason of the files having 13MB and 4MB? Maybe I am losing some information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may read [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) - when you save your model using a `save_model` method you are saving not only weights but also:

- the architecture of the model, allowing to re-create the model,
- the training configuration (loss, optimizer),
- the state of the optimizer, allowing to resume training exactly where you left off.

By using a `save_weights` you are saving only `numpy` arrays with weights values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to be sure, so the checkpoint is similar to save_model? I thought that the checkpoint was saving the weights only

Comment: Yes - by default `Checkpoint` is saving a whole model. But there is `save_weights_only` option - so you can set it to save only weights.

Comment: Awesome, truly appreciated